# Game theory: Is there always only one dominant strategy?

Tags: game-theory

I get the impression that there are two classes of games, ones that have been solved and for whom a dominant strategy exists, and ones that have not been solved and for whom a myriad of strong but not necessarily dominant strategies exist.

**Is it ever the case that a game has more than one non-equivalent dominant strategy?** Or do all cases of games with multiple strong strategies belong to the set of games that have not been solved?

Comment: Are you talking about two person zero sum games with finitely many strategies for each player or about something more general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One cannot have two strictly dominant strategies $\sigma_i$ and $\sigma_i'$ because as $\sigma_i$ is dominant, for all opposing strategies tuples $\sigma_{-i}$:
$$
u_i(\sigma_i, \sigma_{-i}) > u_i(\sigma_i', \sigma_{-i})
$$
but as $\sigma_i'$ is dominant, for all $\sigma_{-i}$:
$$
u_i(\sigma_i', \sigma_{-i}) > u_i(\sigma_i, \sigma_{-i})
$$
which poses a contradiction.  If you mean 'weakly dominant,' so long as your definition of weak dominance is standard (i.e. requires at least one strict comparison), the same argument holds.